# If Then Loop in AutoHotkey to switch between desktops

Tags: loops, if-statement, autohotkey, wait

Let's say ^RButton switches to my right desktop and ^LButton to my left desktop. The probelm then is, that whenever I switch to the right desktop a dropdown menu will open, because I'm using the right mouse button as a hotkey. To counteract this problem, I can add sleep 500 and then send, {Escape} to exit the dropdown menu. So far so good. 
However, if I now want to switch from desktop 1 to desktop 5 I cannot just do 5 ^RButtons in a row but instead have to wait half a second between each click. That's annoying!
I'd be grateful for any ideas on how to avoid having to wait 500 milisecond between each click?
My idea was to work with an if statement. Though I have no idea how to program one...
It would look like this:

```
If ^RButton = True, go to right desktop, 
if after 500 miliseconds there were no further ^RButton clicks, 
then send, {Escape}. 
If there were ^RButton clicks, 
go to the right desktop and wait 500 miliseconds for another ^RButton click,
then send, {Escape}.
```

Would be awesome if someone could transform my text code into AutoHotkey code :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
^RButton:: SendEvent {LWin down}{LCtrl down}{Right down}{LWin up}{LCtrl up}{Right up} ; switch to next virtual desktop
^LButton:: SendEvent {LWin down}{LCtrl down}{Left down}{LWin up}{LCtrl up}{Left up}   ; switch to previous virtual desktop
```

**EDIT:**

As a stand-alone script works for me.

Try also

```
^RButton:: 
    Send {LWin down}{Ctrl down}{Right}{LWin up}{Ctrl up}    ; switch to next virtual desktop
    SetTimer, CloseContextMenu, -50
return

^LButton:: Send {LWin down}{Ctrl down}{Left}{LWin up}{Ctrl up}  ; switch to previous virtual desktop

CloseContextMenu:
    KeyWait, Ctrl, L
    ; Sleep, 300
    Send {Esc}
return
```

https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetTimer.htm

Comment: Does that work for you? For me it doesn't ;(
I tried it out but it still triggers a right click!

Comment: Try to [debug](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Scripts.htm#debug) it or add the hotkeys,functions etc. from your script one by one or group by group to the new script, and test it after saving and reloading.

Comment: I first thought it worked, but it's not a reliable solution. It works when I put it into a new script, but in my script for some reason it doesn't work. 
The edited answer works 50 percent of the time, when using sleep, 300  but is not reliable ;(

Comment: Thank you so much for the debugging hint! Why didn't I come up with that idea ;(
I'm new to programing... I'll try it out immediately. I'll let you know what it was!

Comment: I debugged it and I found out what caused it. 
I'm using a mouse with multiple buttons, so I remapped F1 and F2 to the sidebuttons of my mouse. F1 & LButton = desktop left and F1 & RButton = desktop right. 
What was causing the problem was the following:
`F2 & RButton::Enter`
Do you have an idea why that is causing a problem?

Comment: Replace it with **`F2 & RButton:: Send, {Enter}`**.Remapping key combinations almost always brings problems, the send command is the better option in such cases.

Comment: Thank you so much user3419297!!!!
I was literally spending hours trying to figure this out.
With the Send command it works perfectly!